# Scala Dataframe join and get right table columns only

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark-sql

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1 = Seq(
  (1,"A") 
  ).toDF("id","value")
df1.show()

val df2 = Seq(
  (1,"C") 
  ).toDF("id","value")
df2.show()

val joinKey = "id"
    
df1.join(df2.as("dfy"),joinKey.split(",").toSeq).show()

   

 Output:
    +---+-----+
    | id|value|
    +---+-----+
    |  1|    A|
    +---+-----+
    
    +---+-----+
    | id|value|
    +---+-----+
    |  1|    C|
    +---+-----+
    
    +---+-----+-----+
    | id|value|value|
    +---+-----+-----+
    |  1|    A|    C|
    +---+-----+-----+
```

I want to get only the columns from the right table, including join key 'id'. But since scala skips the duplicate columns, this is not available in the right table if I do as below.

```
df1.as("dfx").join(df2.as("dfy"),joinKey.split(",").toSeq).select($"dfy.*").show()

+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    C|
+-----+
```

This works, but I dont want to get all rows from right table as there can be a lot.

```
 df1.as("dfx").join(df2.as("dfy"),joinKey.split(",").toSeq,"right").select($"dfy.*").show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    C|
+---+-----+
```

what is the best way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what you really want is an inner join, you should just flip the query and use a left_semi join.

```scala
df2.join(df1, joinKey.split(","), "leftsemi").show()
```

Based on you saying the df2 is big, this should even bring you a performance benefit.

Comment: why not keep the order and do a 'rightsemi' ?

Comment: Spark doesn't have right_semi join strangely enough.